# How can I to remove OTRS-module?

Tags: otrs

Few minutes ago, i have made a simplest OTRS module, according this article:

[Writing a new OTRS frontend module](https://otrs.github.io/doc/manual/developer/3.3/en/html/how-to-extend-otrs.html#writing-new-otrs-frontend-module)

```
All is ok. But now, i need to move out this module from OTRS.
How can i do this?

Thanks.
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to delete the files that you have created and than rebuild the config.

In OTRS 5.0.x you can do it by:

> bin/otrs.Console.pl Maint::Config::Rebuild

For older versions:

> bin/otrs.RebuildConfig.pl